# Why is CWnd::MessageBox non-const?

Tags: c++, mfc, messagebox

I am getting this compiler error:

> Error [C2662](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2662?view=msvc-170): `CWnd::MessageBoxA` : cannot convert `this` pointer from `const CEditField` to `CWnd &*`

In the following `const` method:

```cpp
bool CEditField::CanBeChanged() const
{
    bool bCanBeChanged = true;
    // ...
    if (!bCanBeChanged)
    {
        MessageBox("This field is uneditable", "Cannot Edit Field");
    }
    return bCanBeChanged;
}
```

`CEditField` is derived from `CDialog`.

I am working around this by using the WinAPI `MessageBox(this->m_hWnd, ...)`.

**Why would `CWnd::MessageBox` be non-`const`?**

Comment: *Why would CWnd::MessageBox be non-const?* -- Maybe there is a whole lot more in what is going on in `CWnd::MessageBox` than just needing to make a simple call to the WinAPI `MessageBox` function.

Comment: Losing/gaining focus - I bet that's technically it (among other possibilities)???

Comment: On a side note, the [`CWnd::MessageBox()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#messagebox) states: "*Use the global function [`AfxMessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstring-formatting-and-message-box-display?view=msvc-170#afxmessagebox) instead of this member function to implement a message box in your application.*" IOW, Microsoft doesn't even want you to use `CWnd::MessageBox()` in the first place.

Comment: I always use `AfxMessageBox`. You can also override it's default behaviour to adjust how the message boxes get displayed in your app.

Comment: *"Losing/gaining focus - I bet that's technically it"* - There's more: When a modal dialog is displayed, its owner gets deactivated. That's a state change in the associated window (and indeed, the internal `WND` structure gets updated). Now there's an issue that plagues *all* handle wrapper types: Internally, they store a value that never changes, even when the resource referenced through this handle does. There's a disconnect between binary `const`-ness and logical `const`-ness, and library authors get to choose which of those they wish to codify.

Comment: It's possible that the author of this particular member function put a lot of thought into it, and came to the conclusion that they wanted to reflect absence of logical `const`-ness. It's equally likely that I'm completely overthinking this, and the member function simply was born at a time where `const` was mostly perceived as a waste of horizontal screen space. Possibly way back when MFC was still envisioned as the library unifying Windows and classic Mac OS programming.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, `const` is definitely something that evolved (usage-wise) over the lifetime of MFC.  But it would have been easy for them to implement a `const` version (along with the non-`const` version), similar to how you implement `const` and non-`const` accessor methods, one that returns a `const` reference and one that returns a non-`const` reference.

Comment: If you look at the code of MFC , `const` is absent almost everywhere. Even where it made sense. Back in the day when MFC has been built, there was almost no worry about const-correctness. And MFC was simply a wrapper around the Win32 API functionality. Things have evolved and MFC is now a bit far from being only that, and I think they did not place an emphasis on const-correctness with the intent of not breaking an huge base of already existing software.